# How is capacitor leakage rated?

Tags: capacitor

I'm trying to figure out the leakage current of [this](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=216495828&uq=636202740197437379) capacitor. ([the data sheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Samsung%20PDFs/CL_Series_MLCC_ds.pdf))

The best thing i can figure is the insulation resistance. The data sheet calls for 10,000Mohms or 500Mohms*uF which ever is less. If i'm using a 10uF capacitor then the insulation resistance is 500M*10=5000Mohms. I'm using this capacitor at 9v.

Does this mean that the capacitor will leak 1.8nA at 9V or is there some other rating that i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds about right to me. "Leakage Current" is seldom stated directly in a datasheet; I've had to calculate/measure it several times. You should measure yours. The measurements tend to be slightly better than calculated as do most specifications, but expect some variance.

In general, MLCC ceramics will have slightly higher losses than single-layer due to the multi-layering going on. MLCC can be thought of as a bunch of smaller-value caps in parallel. I'm tempted to say "use NP0's in parallel" but then it's almost the same thing but uses more PCB space. I tried a random MLCC in my parts bin vs. several NP0's in parallel and the NP0's won, but not by a landslide.

And for something like a 7mΩ ESR, 6.3v 470uF solid electrolytic - forget it... I measured one at 18mA!

Comment: If basing your design on measurements, be aware that leakage can vary with temperature, humidity and age.